# How to elegantly merge multi-JObjects by group?

Tags: c#, linq

Here I have multi objects, as follows

```
[
{"id": 1, "content": {"a": 1, "b": 2}},
{"id": 2, "content": {"a": 10, "b": 20}},
{"id": 1, "content": {"c": 3, "d": 4}}
]
```

I want to merge the `content` by `id`(group). Finally, get the result

```
[
{"id": 1, "content": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}},
{"id": 2, "content": {"a": 10, "b": 20}}
]
```

Comment: That's very good, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to query with group by. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way I think but it does the job I think. I hope it is understandable.

```
string json = String.Empty;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\Documents\asd.json"))
{
    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

for (int i = 0; i < array.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Count; j++)
    {
        if (array[i]["id"].ToString() == array[j]["id"].ToString())
        {
            foreach (var item in ((JObject)array[j]["content"]).Properties())
            {
                try
                {
                    ((JObject)array[i]["content"][item.Name]).Replace(item);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ((JObject)(array[i]["content"])).Add(item);
                }
            }
            array.Remove(array[j]);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(array.ToString());
```

You can write an universal merger of it without the burned in values easily I think.